# Como comparar uma string de um array em C?

Tags: c, if, for

Eu tenho as seguintes variáveis :

```
char nome[10][8];
int i; --> Sendo esta para o loop
```

Eu peço para o usuário entrar com 5 nomes e depois eu leio a variável :

```
printf("Entre 5 nomes : \n");
for(i=0; i< 5 ; i++)
{
scanf("%s",nome[i]);
}
```

Mas depois disto, eu quero comparar uma string do array e ver se o nome está correto, e caso esteja, ele dispara uma mensagem.

Minha tentativa :

```
for (i=0; i < 1; i++) {
if (nome[i] == "Lucas de Oliveira");
printf("Idade : 18 anos, \nSexo : Masculino, \nEstado civil : Solteiro");
continue;
}
```

Ele aparece a mensagem, mas ele nem sequer termina o primeiro `for` para preencher todos os nomes, e a verificação está um tanto incorreta.

Screenshot :

[image]

Como posso proceder para fazer com que a verificação fique de forma correta, e se somente o nome que for digitado que está dentro do `if`, que apareça a mensagem.

Comment: Você não pode comparar strings diretamente em C. No caso, você está comparando a região da memória entre a constante e o conteúdo em `nome`. Estude a função `strcmp` de `string.h`: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/

Comment: O comando `continue` está sendo usado de maneira errada. Sempre que possível, deixe o laço seguir seu fluxo normal sem fazer interferência em sua execução.

Comment: Mas a função strcmp funciona também para arrays ? Pois ao tentar com ela, da erro.

Comment: Como você testou? E o que você chama de erro? `SIGSEGV`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problemas:**

> - Está usando a função errada para ler a string.
> - Não está comparando a string, mas sim o endereço em que ela se encontra.
> - Pouco espaço na matriz.
> - Não está iterando as vezes necessárias.

Começa organizando o tamanho da matriz:

```
char nome[5][20];
int i;
```

Numa matriz como essa, o que tens são *5 linhas* e *20 colunas*, e o nome *Marcos de Oliveira* possui pelo menos 18 caracteres, o que deve ser ideal.

```
puts("Entre 5 nomes :");
for(i=0; i< 5 ; i++)
{
   scanf("%19[^\n]%*c",nome[i]);
}
```

Nessa parte você pode não usar o `printf` com `\n`, o `puts` é bem mais simples. Naturalmente o `scanf` pára a leitura ao encontrar um espaço vazio quando usando em conjunto com o `%s`, usando essa expressão `%19[^\n]%*c` faz com os espaços vazios sejam utilizados.

```
for(i=0; i < 5; i++) {
    if(!(strcmp(nome[i], "Lucas de Oliveira"))){
        printf("\nNome: %s\nIdade : 18 anos, \nSexo : Masculino, \nEstado civil : Solteiro", nome[i]);
        break;
    }
}
```

Aqui, basta que troques a expressão nos argumentos do `if` utilizando o função `strcmp` que compara duas expressões, e retorna `0` caso sejam idênticas, e também o `i < 1` por `i < 5` que é o tamanho da matriz, senão ele para na primeira iteração, e não avança para os restantes nomes, e claro, o remova o `continue` e coloque `break` no lugar, assim a iteração pára ao encontrar a correspondência.

#### Usando fgets

Em alternativa à expressão dentro do `scanf`, poderias usar o `fgets`:

```
for(i=0; i< 5 ; i++)
{
    fgets(nome[i], 26, stdin);
}
```

Como o `fgets` mantém a quebra `\n`, deve-se antes remover para poder comparar com a palavra pretendida.

```
for(i=0; i < 5; i++) {
        if ((strlen(nome[i])>0) && (nome[i][strlen(nome) - 1] == '\n')){
            nome[i][strlen(nome) - 1] = '\0';
        }   
        if(!(strcmp(nome[i], "Lucas de Oliveira"))){
            printf("\nNome: %s\nIdade : 18 anos, \nSexo : Masculino, \nEstado civil : Solteiro", nome[i]);
            break;
        }
    }
```

> Caso nenhuma ou alguma das funções aqui usadas não estiver a funcionar, veja na documentação por outra alternativa, ou verifique as configurações do compilador em uso.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta, funcionou do modo que eu esperava. Sou novo em C,e por isto cometo diversos erros, mas o bom é que eu aprendo com eles para não cometer eles de novo.

Comment: @Mondial o ideal é continuar a tentar.